# Optimizing a name-deduplication query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

My service receives batches of a few thousand raw records, which among other things contain a name each. Many records are expected to have the same name and thus a deduplication strategy was set up as follows.

The `records` table contains basically all the data from each raw record, except the name which is replaced by an ID pointing to a global `names` table where the `name` column is unique.

I'm using the following query for ETL. For each batch of 5k records, I create one transaction with 5k statements following this query:

```
WITH new_id AS (
    INSERT INTO names
    VALUES (
        DEFAULT,
        @raw_name
    )
    ON CONFLICT (name) 
        DO UPDATE
            SET id = (
                SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = @raw_name
            )
        RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO records VALUES (
    DEFAULT,
    (SELECT id FROM new_id),
    -- other (constant) stuff
);
```

The goal here is to insert the name into the `names` table if it doesn't already exist. In both cases, the name id is retrieved and attached to the record that is inserted into the `records` table.

Executing the transaction takes about 2.5s for 5000 records and I'm looking to optimize the runtime of this query. Temporary memory or table allocations are acceptable. I can also influence the batch size (min. 1k). I have to work with the existing schema (the two tables).

(I also wonder if there is a way to optimize this via concurrency. I can trigger many ETL jobs at once - but the query as it stands will deadlock immediately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your performance issue might comes from the fact that you are iterating over 5000 insert commands. This is a very programatic way of doing work that cannot be optimised by the PostgreSQL engine.

You should try a more declarative approach where you manipulate sets of rows instead of row by row. This way should allow PostgreSQL to do a more efficient work:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE batch (
  name character varying not null,
  txt character varying not null
);

-- INSERT or COPY, depending on where the data comes from
INSERT INTO batch (txt, name) 
VALUES 
  ('txt1','a'),
  ('txt2','a'),
  ('txt3','a'),
  ('txt4','b'),
  ('txt5','b');

INSERT INTO names (name)
  SELECT name FROM batch
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO records (name_id, txt)
  SELECT names.id as name_id, batch.txt 
  FROM batch JOIN names ON names.name = batch.name;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: That is slightly faster. However, on the first pass, it inserts a quasi-random number of rows into the records table (greater than the deduped names, but smaller than the actual number of records). The names table is filled correctly. If I trigger a second pass with the same data, all records are correctly inserted into the records table.

Comment: Oh I get it, this is the `DO NOTHING` part, I will try to fix this. How fast is this for your workload?

Comment: I've hacked together a query generator for this, so without safety checks, it's about 6x faster.

Comment: Nice speed up. Can you run it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and put the result into this tool? https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: [Here's](https://explain.depesz.com/s/kAWC) the explain from the insert stmt generated for batch 0, so the first one.

Comment: Looking at the explain result, PostgreSQL is having a hard time reading from values and inserting all data. I updated the answer to work with an indexed temporary table, this way the join will hopefully be faster. Can you run it with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and put the result into explain.depesz.com please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180617/discussion-between-minxoma-and-clement-prevost).